# lua-sec перестал работать

Tags: lua

При попытке вызвать функцию request получаю в консоль:

```
lua: /usr/share/lua/5.4/ssl/https.lua:66: bad argument #2 to 'method' (string expected, got light userdata)
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'socket.http.request'
        /usr/share/lua/5.4/ssl/https.lua:132: in function 'ssl.https.request'
```

Comment: а где сам вызов?

Comment: @MikeV. `status = https.request(longserver.."?act=a_check&key="..longkey.."&wait=10&mode=2&ts="..ts)`